# Custom Properties Text Font

Tags: api, solidworks

I have created a macro which imports my custom properties to a Solidworks part file. The problem is that Solidworks seems to not understand my chosen VBA text font and imports modified text. Could anyone help me to resolve this problem? [You can see the altered text here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o8jF.jpg)

[image: Solidworks output]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing this with VSTA?

Comment: No Iam not really familiar with VSTA programming

Comment: I think the VBA editor is ASCII extended only. Can you try coding the string using wchar?

Comment: Can you post some of the macro code?  What is the source of the text originally?

Comment: I think that text originally is ASCII but Solidworks uses Unicode

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that i can test this since my install uses the English ASCII encoding and it appears you are using characters I cannot use, but I found this code to convert [ASCII to Unicode](http://blog.brettski.com/2009/12/04/vba-convert-unicode-to-ascii/):

```
Public Function AsciiToUnicode(sText As String) As String
  Dim saText() As String, sChar As String
  Dim sFinal As String, saFinal() As String
  Dim x As Long, lPos As Long

  If Len(sText) = 0 Then
    Exit Function
  End If

  saText = Split(sText, ";") 'Unicode Chars are semicolon separated

  If UBound(saText) = 0 And InStr(1, sText, "&#") = 0 Then
    AsciiToUnicode = sText
    Exit Function
  End If

  ReDim saFinal(UBound(saText))

  For x = 0 To UBound(saText)
    lPos = InStr(1, saText(x), "&#", vbTextCompare)

    If lPos > 0 Then
      sChar = Mid$(saText(x), lPos + 2, Len(saText(x)) - (lPos + 1))

      If IsNumeric(sChar) Then
        If CLng(sChar) > 255 Then
          sChar = ChrW$(sChar)
        Else
          sChar = Chr$(sChar)
        End If
      End If

      saFinal(x) = Left$(saText(x), lPos - 1) & sChar
    ElseIf x < UBound(saText) Then
      saFinal(x) = saText(x) & ";" 'This Semicolon wasn't a Unicode Character
    Else
      saFinal(x) = saText(x)
    End If
  Next

  sFinal = Join(saFinal, "")
  AsciiToUnicode = sFinal

  Erase saText
  Erase saFinal
End Function
```